# Count of answers should have some visual indication other than color

Tags: feature-request

Feature Request: The count of answers should have a some visual indication other than color (e.g. a checkmark icon or whatever) if it contains an "accepted" answer.

Currently, if the answers contain an "accepted" answer, then you can identify this only by the color:

[image: TOP: No accepted answer. BOTTOM: One accepted answer] 
Already on some bright monitors, depending on the viewing angle, you don't see the difference, and color-blind people will have even more problems

Comment: Would you consider editing the feature request to say "a checkmark icon **or some visual indication other than color**"? I don't think there's much support for a checkmark icon, but you have a point about color-only indicators having poor accessibility.

Comment: There is a related request (post anyway) to distinguish whether it is *your* answer which is accepted

Comment: @ChrisBaker Sure - whatever it is !

Comment: It looks like this changed today? (but not on meta?) [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah, you are right! Looks much better now!

Answer (score 8):

You have a point with the contrast - perhaps something should be done about that.

It shouldn't be a check mark, though. That would put way too much an emphasis on accepted answers - much more than they deserve, given that the accept mark is only an indication that *the asker* felt they were helped. There still may be room for an even better answer for future generations.

Comment: Seems it has changed these days!